# Inserting CKEditor specialchar plugin into custom toolbar not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to set custom toolbar in CKEDITOR:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
  [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ],    
  [ 'Image', 'Table' ],
  [ 'specialchar' ]
];
```

The first 2 groups are without problems but the 3rd "specialchar" is not loading.
What am I doing wrong?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martinba/vYYVR/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about capitals.

```
[ 'SpecialChar' ]
```